# KeyboardListener is buggy after focusing a TextField

Tags: flutter

#### Context

This question comes from a github issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67915 still not solved. As I found a workaround I'm posting the question and the solution I found.

#### Question

This is primarily an issue for physical keyboards without touch screens but it is acting weird even with touch screens. I'm trying to support chromebooks with physical keyboard, that's why this issue is blocking me. I have not yet tested enough on slates with bluetooth keyboards but this may be a big problem with those devices too.

I posted this same question in a closed issue here but I didn't get any responses so I guess it's a new bug: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11177

### Steps to Reproduce

I've created a simple repro: https://github.com/mikeesouth/chromebook_keyboard

This repro is as simple as this *(but my repro is slightly improved to show focus and removing unused code)*:

1. `flutter create chromebook_keyboard`
2. Add `final _keyboardListenerFocus = FocusNode();` to the state class
3. Add `String _keyName = 'N/A';` to the state class
4. Override dispose() and call `_keyboardListenerFocus.dispose();` in the state class
5. Add the following to the build method (e.g. as children to the column class):

```
Text('Here is plain TextField:'),
Container(width: 200, child: TextField()),
SizedBox(height: 50),
Text(
    'Tap the green container to show the keycode using a RawKeyboardListener:'),
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () => _keyboardListenerFocus.requestFocus(),
  child: Container(
    width: 200,
    height: 100,
    color: Colors.green,
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: RawKeyboardListener(
      focusNode: _keyboardListenerFocus,
      onKey: (keyEvent) => setState(
          () => _keyName = keyEvent.data.logicalKey.debugName),
      child: Text('keyName = $_keyName'),
    ),
  ),
),
```

**Expected results:**
I expect the physical keyboard to work for the TextField and the physical keyboard to also work for the RawKeyboardListener when pressing the green container (to set focus to the keyboard listener). I expect the RawKeyboardListener to register keys (e.g. "A") when it's focused.

**Actual results:**
The actual result is that the RawKeyboardListener listens correctly if I focus it before focusing the TextField after application startup. But as soon as I focus the TextField and then switch back the focus to the RawKeyboardListener - then it does not register keys correctly.
If you start with the green container (keyboard listener) it recognizes all keys (i.e a, b, c, 1, 2, 3, space, left alt, left shift and so on). If you switch to the text field you can type text as expected. If you switch back to the green container - it no longer recognizes text, only modifiers such as left alt, left shift etc. BUT if you hold left alt, then it also recognizes letters and other keys (i.e. alt + a will display "_keyName = A"). Restart the app - the KeyboardListener works again but as soon as you focus the TextField the RawKeyboardListener will no longer recognize key presses.

**Test device:**
I'm trying this on a Chromebook without touch screen and it (of course) has a physical keyboard. The model is `HP Chromebook 14-db0004no 14"`.

**Additional information - buggy on touch screens:**
Another interesting thing is that the keyboard listener correctly listens even after focusing the TextField. But an issue that may be related is that when I focus the TextField the soft keyboard shows as soon as I press a key on the physical keyboard - is this intended?

Steps to reproduce this issue that may be related:

1. Start the app
2. Tap the green container (to focus RawKeyboardListener)
3. Press some keys (e.g. a, b, c) on my physical keyboard (Windows) - it registers correctly and no soft keyboard is displayed
4. Tap the TextField (to focus it) - the soft keyboard pops up
5. Type some text (e.g. "Hello World")
6. Press back key on emulator to hide keyboard
7. Tap the green container again (to focus RawKeyboardListener)
8. Press some keys - the soft keyboard pops up again - why? *(side note: on the Android Emulator this still registers the keypresses, on my Chromebook, this wouldn't recognize the keypresses if I don't hold down alt as described above)*

I haven't started to test this on a hybrid device (i.e. touch screen + physical keyboard) but if the soft keyboard pops up focusing a text field when using a hybrid device with an attached keyboard, then it will become an issue for us. We would like to control when the soft keyboard shows up - it would be OK for it to show up automatically on a touch screen device without an attached keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is: RawKeyboardListener works nicely but stops listening as soon as a text field is focused

So you need to find a way to use the keyboard without having to focus the `TextField`.

- you need to set `readOnly` to `true` for the `TextField` this way you cannot focus it
- now you need to manually show the keyboard when you Tap your `TextField` with `openKeyboard()`
- create the function `thisHandle` to modify the content of your `TextField` according to the key pressed

The `ScanReader` example widget below allow you to scan a qrCode or type with the virtual keyboard.

```dart
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_barcode_listener/flutter_barcode_listener.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true),
      home: const Root(),
    );
  }
}

class ScanReader extends HookWidget {
  final void Function(String value) onScan;

  const ScanReader({super.key, required this.onScan});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var controller = useState<TextEditingController>(TextEditingController());
    var keyboardShowed = useState<bool>(false);

    openKeyboard() {
      keyboardShowed.value = true;
      SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod("TextInput.show");
    }

    closeKeyboard() {
      keyboardShowed.value = false;
      SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod("TextInput.hide");
      controller.value.clear();
    }

    useEffect(() {
      thisHandle(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        if (keyboardShowed.value == false) {
          return false;
        }
        if (keyEvent.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.backspace &&
            controller.value.text.isNotEmpty) {
          controller.value.text = controller.value.text
              .substring(0, controller.value.text.length - 1);
        } else if (keyEvent.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.enter) {
          onScan(controller.value.text);
          closeKeyboard();
        } else {
          var newChar = keyEvent.character.toString();
          if (newChar.length == 1) {
            controller.value.text += newChar;
          }
        }
        return true;
      }

      HardwareKeyboard.instance.addHandler(thisHandle);
      return () {
        HardwareKeyboard.instance.removeHandler(thisHandle);
      };
    }, []);

    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        BarcodeKeyboardListener(
          bufferDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
          onBarcodeScanned: (newBarcode) {
            if (newBarcode != '') {
              onScan(newBarcode);
            }
          },
          useKeyDownEvent: Platform.isWindows,
          child: TextField(
            autofocus: false,
            readOnly: true,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            controller: controller.value,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              suffixIcon: IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.close),
                onPressed: () {
                  closeKeyboard();
                },
              ),
              hintText: 'Search...',
            ),
            onTap: () {
              openKeyboard();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class Root extends HookWidget {
  const Root({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: ScanReader(onScan: (String value) {
          print('$value');
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```